# Getting list index out of range when running CmcScraper

Tags: python

I am running the following code to receive data on each coin from CMsScraper. However, it appears that data for some of the coins is not available, and this breaks my loop. How can I make the loop to continue even when a particular coin data is not available?

```
import pandas as pd
from cryptocmd import CmcScraper

coins_list = []

coins = ['VIU', 'UTS', 'UVU', 'TRM']

for i in coins:

  scraper = CmcScraper(i, start_date="01-01-2017", end_date="01-04-2023")
  data = scraper.get_data()
  coins_list.append(data)
```

Even this does not work:

```
from cryptocmd.utils import InvalidCoinCode
from cryptocmd import CmcScraper

coins = ['VIU', 'UTS', 'UVU', 'HNC', 'TRM']

for i in coins:
  try:
    scraper = CmcScraper(i, start_date="01-01-2017", end_date="01-04-2023")
    data = scraper.get_data()
    print(f"{i} is available through the CoinMarketCap API.")
  except InvalidCoinCode:
    print(f"{i} is not available through the CoinMarketCap API.")
```

Comment: It's a bug in the library. I'd just open an issue on Github and hope the maintainer is responsive. But to answer your question your try except isn't working because the exception raised is an `IndexError` and not `InvalidCoinCode`.

Comment: in the meantime, is there any way around?

Comment: Removing `'TRM'` from the list. The others work.

Comment: I have like 150 coins... this was just a sample list

Comment: In that case go with your try except approach
, but replace InvalidCoinCode with IndexError

Comment: Or catch both exceptions if necessary

Comment: For completeness, it'd help to post the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341).